# Irregular intervals in Excel graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

As you can see in the image, I need to have irregular intervals but to have that I tried to leave 6(for 60 min) empty columns to have that gap but that makes it not draw or connect the first point to the rest of the lines. Also, the First point looks like a single point but it has 4 points at the same spot.

I could find the Line equation and find the points inbetween but that would take time as i need to do this a lot of times. I have simulated a rough estimate of how the data is below.

I want to know how i can deal with this situation

```
   A     B    C    D     E     F     G
Line 1 0.665             0.659 0.606 0.553
Line 2 0.665             0.639 0.590 0.526
  .
  .
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click anywhere in your chart and from the menu choose "Select Data...". Then, click the button in the lower left corner labeled "Hidden and Empty Cells".

From there, select "Show empty cells as:  Connect data points with line" and click OK all the way out.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Before you go any further, make sure you are using a **scatter plot** chart and NOT a line chart. You can set up your scatter plot to show only connecting lines, and your data points will be spaced appropriately automatically without any klugey workarounds.

Comment: This also worked but I cannot choose two answers. I(actually my friend) was already using scatter plot and i dont know what he did but it was taking the intervals as names instead of intervals and was not scaling.
Otherwise just using scatter plot should work fine.
Maybe because of the text in the interval row made it to be names rather than intervals

Comment: Text in the X Values range will mess up the numerical spacing in an XY chart, and the chart will just use the counting numbers as X values, ignoring any numbers in the range.